# R Shiny dq_render_handsontable Error when adding columns and trying to Edit new columns' cells

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I get an error while using shiny `dq_render_handsontable` which I guess it's a bug of the dq_shiny package. I would appreciate if anyone could know any work around.
I am trying to interactively update a table via an action button ("Generate" in the code below). The tables which I am trying to switch among, have different number of columns. All works up to the display of the new table, i.e., once I click on "Generate" I can see the new table with additional columns. BUT the problem is that once I try to edit the cells of the data frame with a more columns after editting the first one with less columns, the following error appear:

```
Warning: Error in [<-.data.frame: new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

I guess that is certainly a bug of `dq_render_handsontable` that doesn't recognize the new columns added to `handsontable`. Anyone knows a workaround? Maybe refreshing the table before showing a new data frame with more columns?

I attach the peice of the code to reproduce the error:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dqshiny)
library(rlang)

  ui = fluidPage(


    dq_handsontable_output("InputTable", 9)
    ,
    # actionButton("render", "Render HoT"),
    actionButton("simulationInput_2", "Generate"),
    fluidRow(id="bigRow", class="hidden",
             style="height:100vh;background:#ff8f00;")
  )

  server = function(input, output) {
    hw <- c("Hello", "my", "funny", "world!")
    data1 <- data.frame(A=hw, B=hw[c(2,3,4,1)], C=1:4, D=Sys.Date() - 0:3,
                        A2=hw, B2=hw[c(2,3,4,1)], C2=1:4, D2=Sys.Date() - 1:4,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    hw <- c("Hello", "my", "funny", "world!")
    data2 <- data.frame(A=hw, B=hw[c(2,3,4,1)], C=1:4, D=Sys.Date() - 0:3,
                        # A2=NA, B2=NA, C2=NA, D2=NA,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    cont = 0


    observeEvent(input$simulationInput_2, {
      cont <<- cont+1
      print(cont)
      if(mod(cont,2)==0){
        data <- data2
      }else{
        data <- data1
      }
      renderInputTable(data)
      render_hot("InputTable")
      })

    renderInputTable <- function(data){
      dq_render_handsontable(
      "InputTable",
                           data, #"rand",
                           # filters = F, #c("S", "T", "R", "R"),
                           filters = rep(NA, ncol(data)),
                           table_param = list(rowHeaders = NULL, selectCallback = TRUE))

    }

    observeEvent(input$random_select, toggle("bigRow"))
    observeEvent(input$render, render_hot("InputTable"))
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could overcome the problem by a trick which is renaming the dq_shiny table ID which is actually a bug of `dq_render_handsontable`:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dqshiny)
library(rlang)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)


ui = fluidPage(
  tags$div(id="simulationInputTable_divOutside", style="padding:0px;margin:0px",
           tags$div(id="simulationInputTable_divInside1", style="padding:0px;margin:0px",
                    dq_handsontable_output("InputTable1", 9)),
           tags$div(id="simulationInputTable_divInside2", style="padding:0px;margin:0px",
                    dq_handsontable_output("InputTable2", 9)),
           tags$div(id="simulationInputTable_divInside3", style="padding:0px;margin:0px",
                    dq_handsontable_output("InputTable3", 9))
  )
  ,
  # actionButton("render", "Render HoT"),
  actionButton("simulationInput_2", "Generate"),
  fluidRow(id="bigRow", class="hidden",
           style="height:100vh;background:#ff8f00;")
)
server = function(input, output) {
  columns <- c(1,2,3,4)
  hw <- c("Hello", "my", "funny", "world!")

  cont = 0
  observeEvent(input$simulationInput_2, {
    cont <<- cont+1
    data1 <- data.frame(A=hw, B=hw[c(2,3,4,1)], C=1:4, D=Sys.Date() - 0:3,
                        A2=hw, B2=hw[c(2,3,4,1)], C2=1:4, D2=Sys.Date() - 1:4,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    name = paste0("InputTable",cont)
    divName = paste0("simulationInputTable_divInside",cont-1)
    hide(divName)
    dq_render_handsontable(
      name,
      data1, #"rand",
      # filters = F, #c("S", "T", "R", "R"),
      filters = rep(NA, ncol(data1)),
      table_param = list(rowHeaders = NULL, selectCallback = TRUE))
  })
  observeEvent(input$random_select, toggle("bigRow"))
  observeEvent(input$render, render_hot("InputTable"))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```